# IntelliJ messes up CSS Code Style, adds spaces before colon (Community Edition)

Tags: css, intellij-idea, sass, format

I tried using IntelliJ Community Edition for Frontend Development (on Mac OS) but then I noticed, that after saving a SCSS file, the code gets aligned in a way that I don't want and since there are no Code Style settings for CSS in the Community Edition, I don't know where that's coming from.

The CSS is formatted like this on save:

from this (what I write and what I want)

```
.class {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

to this (what it's getting formatted into and what I dont want)

```
.class {
    display      : block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

There is no setting like "align on colon" or "spaces before colon" or sth like that. I searched for "align", "colon" and "space" in the settings panel but haven't found a setting that forces this formatting behaviour.

**PLUS:** It still gets formatted like this when deleting the .idea folder, working with my previous Editor (Atom), and deleting all the added spaces manually.

Hope someone can help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Community edition has no advanced CSS support, so no code formatters are there. You must have some tool (triggered on saving) that changes your file. Is is `*.scss` or `*.css`, BTW? You mentioned both in your post

Comment: Don't think that stylistic choices are just an aesthetic matter. Here the alignment in columns makes it easier to find the properties either during their development or when updating the code. Aligning the `:` makes it possible to verify that they are not missing. Think about those whose job it is to check other people's code for years.